# What is the name for the part of a whistle where its string goes through?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to find the word which refers to the part of a whistle shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know the exact term (if there's any) or a name by which it's commonly referred to as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Eyelet](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eyelet):***

> - a small hole, usually round and finished along the edge, as in cloth or leather for the passage of a lace or cord or as in embroidery for ornamental effect.

(Dictionary.com)